# Removing CheckBox Column from dataGridView while importing to iTextSharp

Tags: c#, datagridview, itext

I am importing DataGridview to Itextsharp, imports fine however i also have a checkbox column in the grid and i do not want to import that column in the pdf, is there any way to omit that.

Below is the code.

```
PdfPTable pdfTable9 = new PdfPTable(dataGridView2.ColumnCount);
pdfTable9.SetWidths(new float[] { 5f, 10f, 10f, 7f, 9f, 3f});
pdfTable9.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
pdfTable9.WidthPercentage = 100;
pdfTable9.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
pdfTable9.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView2.Columns)
{
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText,   fontTitle2));
    cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
    pdfTable9.AddCell(cell);
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
     foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
     {
          pdfTable9.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), fontTitle));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an IDE at the moment so there might be a typo below but you can either just hard-code the known index into skip logic or you can inspect each `column` object.

```
//Set our skip column to an invalid index to start with
var colToSkip = -1;

//Index loop variable
var i = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView2.Columns)
{
    if( column is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)
    {
        colToSkip = i;
    }
    else
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText,   fontTitle2));
        cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
        pdfTable9.AddCell(cell);
    }
    i++;
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
     i = 0;
     foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
     {
         if( i != colToSkip )
         {
             pdfTable9.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), fontTitle));
         }
         i++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Great, its excluding the last column while importing to PDF however the header is missing. Please help